# Match text with XPATH syntax

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

Exmple feed: view-source:http://rss.packetstormsecurity.org/files/tags/exploit/

I only want to return sections of xml where the parent title node has matching text in it, in this example the text to match is "site".

```
 //get feed with curl

 $doc = new SimpleXmlElement($xml, LIBXML_NOCDATA);

 //$result = $doc->xpath('//title'); //this works returns all the <title>'s

 $result = $doc->xpath('//title[site]');                     //doesn't work
 $result = $doc->xpath('//title[text()="site"]');           //doesn't work
 $result = $doc->xpath('//title[contains(site)]');           //doesn't work
 $result = $doc->xpath('//title[contains(text(),'Site')]');  //doesn't work


 foreach ($result as $title)
 echo "$title<br />"
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The call you need is, I think, this:

```
$result = $xpath->query('//title[contains(.,"Site")]');
```

Note that this is case-sensitive.

Note that the [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPath/Functions/contains) XPath function takes two arguments: a haystack and a needle.  In this case, we are using the current node's text value as the haystack, which is indicated by the use of the dot (`.`).

Comment: +1 Correct answer. You wrote *"we are using the current node"*. But `fn:contains()` function expects two string data type arguments, so `self::node()` abbreviated syntax (`.`) will be casted with `fn:string()` function, returning its **string value**: concatenation of all descendant text nodes.